# Using auth0 with Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, auth0, laravel-5.3

I am trying to use [auth0](https://auth0.com) with Laravel 5.3. I wrote following code

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.2/lock.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lock = new Auth0Lock('M0pdPK3bUKwYuHzK3Lxx8CWEFtu0Qv2X', 'foysal.auth0.com', {
    auth: {
      redirectUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1/addbook/auth0/callback',
      responseType: 'code',
      params: {
        scope: 'openid email' // Learn about scopes: https://auth0.com/docs/scopes
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is my callback settings in auth0

[image]

But while I am trying to login I got below error

[image]

Could any one say where is the issue ??

Comment: Looks like your application route is not properly defined to handle the request.

Comment: Show us your route definition for `addbook/auth0/callback` please. Do your other Laravel routes work properly?

Comment: @ceejayoz, Here is the route `Route::get('auth0/callback', ['as' => 'logincallback', 'uses' => '\Auth0\Login\Auth0Controller@callback']);`

Comment: @abuabu Where's the `addbook` coming from?

Comment: **addbook** is the project name as well as folder name inside **htdocs** folder. Thanks

Comment: @abuabu Then the URL to this page is likely to be `addbook/public/auth0/callback` because of the Laravel folder structure.

Comment: @ceejayoz, are you talking about this portion  Route::get(**'auth0/callback'**, ['as' => 'logincallback', 'uses' => '\Auth0\Login\Auth0Controller@callback']); ?? Should it be like this `Route::get('addbook/public/auth0/callback', ['as' => 'logincallback', 'uses' => '\Auth0\Login\Auth0Controller@callback']);` ??

Comment: @abuabu No. Leave your route declaration alone. I'm saying your `redirectUrl` probably needs the `public` folder in the URL, as that's apparently how you've set up your server. You shouldn't do that in production, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I think you should define your GET variables in the route. This way you also keep the URL's nice and clean.

```
Route::get('auth0/callback/{code}', ['as' => 'logincallback', 'uses' => '\Auth0\Login\Auth0Controller@callback']);
```

Since it's a 404, try my above code and instead of doing `?code=xxx` just add the code after the `callback/` (Suggest to try both URL's)

This javascript could make sure your url is valid:

```
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.2/lock.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var lock = new Auth0Lock('M0pdPK3bUKwYuHzK3Lxx8CWEFtu0Qv2X', 'foysal.auth0.com', {
   auth: {
      redirectUrl: '{!!route('logincallback') !!}',
      responseType: 'code',
      params: {
        scope: 'openid email'
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Also, unless you have CORS errors in your console, there are no cors errors. But if you stumble on them later it's probably because you are using 127.0.0.1 which could cause issues. In that case you should use localhost instead.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I had the same error. Did you put http://127.0.0.1 in the CORS accepted urls box. I believe it's in the same page as the callback urls. That worked for me.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to CORS headers. OP is getting a 404 on the route.

Comment: Ok sorry. I was also getting a 404. Must have been a different one.